# Ubuntu Server 22 vs Marvell 88se9172

Tags: server, raid

I'm trying to run the Ubuntu Server 22 install on a system with a Marvell 88se9172 RAID controller. But the installer does not detect either the array or the individual disks.

The array is up and running, I've been able to install an instance of Windows on it (I completely wiped and rebuilt the array after that, it was a test to validate the array was operational.)

I also have documentation here that the driver for the array exists in the Linux kernel: https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:1b4b-9172-1458-b000

But I can't seem to find documentation any Ubuntu documentation regarding supported RAID drivers.

If anybody can point me in the right direction, either to the documentation or to a solution, that'd be great.